# how to put complete website features in iphone application

Tags: iphone

I am developing iphone version of Youtube like website.
my client wants that all features that are in website which are community,groups,login etc must also be available in iphone application.
any idea how should i work.
i have already develop Multi RSS application but this one in which their will be database interaction also in newer for me.
please guide me. I will wait for your response.

Answer (score 3):

You need to be researching webservice technology and integration I should think, and I think the question is far too broad to be able to answer sufficiently here.

However I'm going to suggest that your client would be better off spending the money developing a mobile-friendly version of the website.  This would be mainly HTML and CSS work, and obviously has the benefits of not only supporting the iPhone, but other phones that have decent browsers built in.

Answer (score 1):

Mobile applications really benefit from a rethinking of the UI.  You can keep most of your functionality, but it should generally be exposed differently.

Look into something like [Phone Gap](http://www.phonegap.com/) which lets you create an app completely with HTML/javascript/CSS etc.  Of course, you'll have to change all your UI elements to accommodate the iPhone/iPad UI standards, but if your site has separated it's 'view' nicely this may be a reasonable task.  But more likely, you are better off re-thinking the UI and restarting.